# JS table row drag and drop without Jquery UI in 2016

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

There are a lot of answer on of using jQuery UI to do drag and drop, most of them are out of date and years old.  What is the best plugin in 2016 to implement Drag n Drop for table row with jQuery (without jQuery UI)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Good day, Yongke Yu!
Try a library by Konstanin Levedev— «[Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable)» (~6KB). In NPM — «sortablejs».
This library is very flexible, without the dependencies, with the touch support, with the ability to add items on the fly.

I did a [demo](http://codepen.io/asakasinsky/full/zqpawR/) for you. Try to add and remove rows, and reorder them.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS table row drag and drop without Jquery UI in 2016</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="recipe">
        <div class="recipe__info">
            <h2 class="recipe__title">Banana muffins recipe</h2>
            <p>These healthy muffins are the perfect treat for when you are feeling something sweet. It is so much better to bake muffins yourself as you can choose exactly what you put in them, meaning you can stay away from refined sugars and preservatives! These are perfect for bringing to a brunch or just sharing with your friends.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe__ingredients">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="recipe-table" id="recipeTable">
                <tbody id="recipeTableBody">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="drag-handler"></td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="Large bananas" placeholder="Ingredient">
                        </td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="3" placeholder="Value">
                        </td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <button class="recipe-table__del-row-btn">x</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="drag-handler"></td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="White sugar" placeholder="Ingredient">
                        </td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="¹⁄₂" placeholder="Value">
                        </td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <button class="recipe-table__del-row-btn">x</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="drag-handler"></td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="Egg" placeholder="Ingredient">
                        </td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="1" placeholder="Value">
                        </td>
                        <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                            <button class="recipe-table__del-row-btn">x</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="recipe-table__add-row">
                <span class="recipe-table__add-row-btn">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/template">
        <tr>
            <td class="drag-handler"></td>
            <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="" placeholder="Ingredient">
            </td>
            <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                <input type="text" class="recipe__text-field" value="" placeholder="Value">
            </td>
            <td class="recipe-table__cell">
                <button class="recipe-table__del-row-btn">x</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.recipe {
    padding: 1em;
}

.recipe__title {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.recipe__info {
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    margin: 0 1.3em 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #454545;
    border-right: 1px dotted #EEE;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.recipe__ingredients {
    float: left;
}

.recipe-table {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px -10px rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}

.recipe-table__cell {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

.recipe__text-field {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .45em 0.92em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.recipe-table__add-row {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
    z-index: 8;
}

.recipe-table__add-row-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 4em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s easy-in;
    transition: all .2s easy-in;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #16A085;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    background: #16A085;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.recipe-table__add-row-btn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.recipe-table__del-row-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .45em 0.92em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    border: 1px solid #F39C12;
    color: #F39C12;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.recipe-table__del-row-btn:hover {
    background: #F39C12;
    color: #fff;
}

.drag-handler {
    width: 1.4em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #E4E6EB;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E4E6EB, #E4E6EB 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #E4E6EB 4px, #E4E6EB 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #E4E6EB 11px, #E4E6EB 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #E4E6EB 18px, #E4E6EB 22px);
    background-size: 10px 20px;
    cursor: move;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.drag-handler:active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #bab86c, #bab86c 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #bab86c 4px, #bab86c 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #bab86c 11px, #bab86c 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #bab86c 18px, #bab86c 22px);
    background-size: 10px 20px;
}
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.recipe-table__add-row-btn', function (e) {
        var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
        var $tableBody = $('#recipeTableBody');
        var htmlString = $('#rowTemplate').html();
        $tableBody.append(htmlString);
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.recipe-table__del-row-btn', function (e) {
        var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
        var $row = $el.closest('tr');
        $row.remove();
        return false;
    });
    Sortable.create(
        $('#recipeTableBody')[0], {
            animation: 150,
            scroll: true,
            handle: '.drag-handler',
            onEnd: function () {
                console.log('More see in https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, experiment ended successfully?

Comment: Yes indeed!  Thank you.

Comment: is it possible to save the order to database? because right now if you refresh the order is resetting

Comment: You can get an order index of rows for save. Set handler for onEnd event, and rewrite order index in data-attr or in hidden fields.

Comment: I've tried the demo, but reordering of rows doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post and that it already has an Answer... but the questions said it didn't wanted JQuery on it and the current answer has JQuery to work. I would recommend Rowsorter.js (https://github.com/arteyazilim/rowsorter)

It's super easy to use and the examples on the GitHub are easy to understand and apply them to any table you already have.